# delete a pid file even after the running php being aborted or force killed

Tags: php

I have a little question about PHP
I have the following PHP code:

```
define('PIDFILE', 'pid.txt');
file_put_contents(PIDFILE, posix_getpid());
function removePidFile() {
    unlink(PIDFILE);
}
register_shutdown_function('removePidFile');
```

Then I execute the script on the command line using `[root@xx]# php test.php`

The code successfully deletes the `pid` file if it runs to completion,
but NOT if a user force kills it, like example using `CTRL+C` to abort.
Then the `pid` file is not deleted.

Now the question:
How to ensure the `pid` file is deleted even a user forces a `kill` or `abort` the running process?

Comment: In short: you can't.